# How to return SQL Server 2005/2008 columns as identical child nodes using FOR XML query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, for-xml

Basically I need to return some data from a SQL Server table in the following XML format:

```
<querydata>
  <entity name="Person.Contact">
    <row>
      <field name="FirstName">Gustavo</field>
      <field name="LastName">Achong</field>
    </row>
    <row>
      <field name="FirstName">Catherine</field>
      <field name="LastName">Abel</field>
    </row>
...
  </entity>
</querydata>
```

I have come up with the following SQL statement:

```
select 'Person.Contact' as "@name", 
(select FirstName, LastName from Person.Contact for XML path('row'), TYPE)
for XML path('entity'), root('querydata')
```

Which produces this output:

```
<querydata>
  <entity name="Person.Contact">
    <row>
      <FirstName>Gustavo</FirstName>
      <LastName>Achong</LastName>
    </row>
    <row>
      <FirstName>Catherine</FirstName>
      <LastName>Abel</LastName>
    </row>
....
  </entity>
</querydata>
```

But I have gotten no further.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Rob!  You definitely got me on the right track, +1 for you!  I had to wrap everything in a SELECT * FROM statement, otherwise SQL server complains.  Here is the final working query:

```
SELECT 'Person.Contact' as "@name",
(SELECT 
    (SELECT * from (SELECT 'FirstName' as [@name], [FirstName] as [*]
    union all
    SELECT 'LastName' as [@name], [LastName] as [*]) y
    for xml path('field'), TYPE)
from Person.Contact for XML path, TYPE)
for XML path('entity'), root('querydata')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpivot your data.

Try using a subquery along the lines of:

```
SELECT 'FirstName' as [@name], FirstName as [*]
union all
SELECT 'LastName' as [@name], LastName as [*]
for xml path('field')
```

Or something along these lines...

I don't have SQL with me (on my iPhone today), but I'm thinking about:

```
select 'Person.Contact' as "@name", 
(select (SELECT 'FirstName' as [@name], FirstName as [*]
union all
SELECT 'LastName' as [@name], LastName as [*]
for xml path('field')) from Person.Contact for XML path('row'), TYPE)
for XML path('entity'), root('querydata')
```